# Long polling ajax structure issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, long-polling, .post

So I found this good example of long-polling, but I couldn't figure out how to transfer variables through it. This is what I came up with, but it doesn't work. I'm pretty confident the issue is with the dataString and type, because that's the part of the code I modified.

```
$(".post").each(function() {
    poll("somestuff");
});


(function poll(pid) {
    var dataString = 'pid=' + pid;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/site/execs/something.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {

            alert('stuff');


        },
        dataType: "json",
        complete: poll,
        timeout: 30000
    });
})();​
```

Can someone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the scope of `poll`, hegemon's answer is mostly correct – the function is not global.  However, there's more to it.

The way you've written `poll` makes it what's known as a *named function expression*.

Remember that there are two ways of writing functions in JavaScript.  The traditional *function declaration*:

```
function foo() {
    ...
}
```

Declarations *must* be named, and are [hoisted](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) to the top (basically, parsed before any instructions are executed).  Alternatively, *function expressions*:

```
var foo = function() {
    ...
}
```

Or

```
$.ajax('/', function() {
    // this is what's known as an anonymous callback
});
```

Or

```
(function() {
    // this is called a self-executing function...
})(); // <-- because we call it immediately
```

Expressions are executed like any other code; they are not hoisted.

And now the fun part: function expressions may be given an *optional* name, but that name is not accessible outside the scope of the function itself.  In other words,

```
(function foo() {
    // `foo` is this function
});

// `foo` will be undefined here
```

Would be much like writing this:

```
(function () {
    var foo = arguments.callee; // never do this
    // `foo` is this function
});

// `foo` will be undefined here
```

Because of the fact that a named function expression can only call itself (or be called by a function declared inside its scope), plus [a whole host of browser bugs](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/), **named function expressions are virtually useless** outside of adding some context in a debugger or profiler.

---

So now let's walk through your code.

First, you walk through each element that has a `post` class.  jQuery immediately invokes your anonymous callback for each matching element.  You try to call `poll`, but it:

1. Doesn't exist yet because function expressions are not hoisted; the `poll` code has not run yet.
2. Even if it had already run (say, if you moved the `$.each` call to the bottom), `post` would still be undefined because `poll` is a named function expression, and we just learned that those identifiers are only available inside of the function itself.

Next, you have a self-executing function.  (The `()` on the very last line.)  In other words, `poll` is invoked immediately with no arguments.  You're probably seeing a single long-poll sending `pid=undefined`.

*Bonus:* The `complete` callback (to begin a new long-poll after one times out or gets data) *does* work as expected, since `poll` is properly in scope at that point.

Fixing all this nonsense is as easy as removing three characters.  Hopefully, by this point you're able to figure out which three characters those are.  (Hint: make your expression a declaration.)

Comment: I don't know if I actually figured out what it is I am supposed to do. There were 4 characters I removed, the initial ( then the )() at the end, however this works once. It executes immediately but it doesn't seem to execute again after that. So the connection does not stay open, works once then fails...

Answer (score 2):

You `poll()` function never gets registered in the global scope. That's becouse it is enclosed by "`(...)()`" construct which basically means: call "`...`" with no arguments and forget.

Comment: This answer is correct in that `poll` is not global.  However, it is a bit misleading in saying that the reason is the parens (or even the self-executing function).  I've posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10201107/201952) with more.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to answer perhaps...

Scope issue aside, your poll function isn't polling. It's only an ajax request.

To make it poll you need to call setTimeout. So your code would look like:

```
(function poll(pid) {
    var dataString = 'pid=' + pid;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/site/execs/something.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {

                alert('stuff');


            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: poll,
            timeout: 30000
        });
    })
})();
```